# iOS App crashes because KVO observer is not observing anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

Is there a way to know if there are objects listening on a keypath for a view controller. For example, I have in my viewcontroller

```
[tabBarController addObserver:self
     forKeyPath:@"selectedViewController"
     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
     context:&PrivateKVOContext
]; (edited)
```

And I want to know if my tabbarcontroller can know if my viewcontroller is listening on that keypath

The reason is because my app crashes because the tab bar controller still thinks my view controller is listening on that key path even though my view controller has been deallocated

And in the dealloc method of my viewcontroller, I put `[tabBarController removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedViewController”];` to remove itself as an observer

Comment: If observer is not getting removed, try write `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observerObjectHere]` in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Kind of a tangent but why should a view controller in a tab bar controller care when a different tab is selected? That sounds like a poor design.

Comment: Why don't you subclass tabBarController and create protocol with use of which you'll be able to send delegates message that selectedViewController is changed. It will be clearer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not. There's no way to check which objects are currently observing other objects.

As such, it's generally recommended that you place `removeObserver:` in the complementing method to the one where you placed `addObserver:` so they'll be reliably called an equal number of times.

In this case, since you're putting it in dealloc, which is called at the end of the view controller's lifecycle, you should put `addObserver:` in your `init` method, which will be called at the very start.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on if the observer really in use, in your code , try this:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    @try {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:Notification_Location_Ready];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

    } @finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: **Do not** use this, please. `try-catch` is a complete **bad practice**. This only hides the obvious error in the code, it does not fix it. Instead, he should create some structure to keep references to the observers and then remove them when appropiate.